# Get last two number in 2018

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to trim `JAN2018` and get last  value like this =>`JAN18`. how I can  ?

Comment: if its string then use substring, if its date then use format

Comment: How about `RIGHT('JAN2018', 2)` ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can use  `Trim`,`concat` and  `SUBSTR` function

`SELECT SUBSTR("Tutorial", 5, 3) AS ExtractString;` it will return "ria"

For your case

```
SELECT concat( SUBSTR(Trim( ' JAN2018'),1,3), SUBSTR(Trim( ' JAN2018'),-2));
```

For more knowledge on [Concat](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_mysql_concat.asp), [Trim](https://www.w3resource.com/mysql/string-functions/mysql-trim-function.php) and [SUBSTR](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_mysql_substr.asp)

Comment: Sorry i forgot to mention that i want to replace JAN2018 to JAN18

Comment: then use concat function with this

Comment: SELECT insert("JAN2018", 4,2, '') AS removetwochar; //output will be JAN2018

Comment: @ZaynulAbadinTuhin what if the year is 1999 ?

Comment: @Rajapandian I am sorry for edit the answer of yours

Comment: @lucumt  happens :)

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT SUBSTRING("JAN2018", -2) AS endtwochar; //if you have one char then will return empty
SELECT right("JAN2018",  2) AS endtwochar; // if you have on char then you will one char
```

Both should give same result - decide based on output

if you need output JAN18 then try below

```
SELECT insert("JAN2018", 4,2, '') AS removetwochar;
```

Comment: Sorry i forgot to mention that i want to replace JAN2018 to JAN18

Comment: `insert()` is the best function to use.

Answer (score 1):

Hope this query may help you:

```
SELECT RIGHT(columnname,2) FROM tablename;
```

Here is a [demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/a4994b/2)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `SUBSTR()`

```
  SELECT SUBSTR('JAN2018',-2);
```

---

For your new requirement(an ugly way):

```
  SELECT REPLACE('JAN2018','20','')
```

Comment: Sorry i forgot to mention that i want to replace JAN2018 to JAN18

Answer (score 0):

Give this a try, this is the query to find last two digit from date

```
select substr(to_char(sysdate),length(to_char(sysdate))-1,2) last_two from dual
```